# IntelliJ lombok plugin isn't compatible

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, lombok

Lombok plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Ultimate Edition) isn't compatible with this IDE instance. I don't know if it is a problem just in my machine or is it in everybody's machine:

[image]

Is it fixable? Or is it a temporary issue?

Comment: When I hit such an issue, I usually update the `until-build` attribute on the `idea-version` tag in `META-INF/plugin.xml` (`<idea-version since-build="145.258.11" until-build="171.*"/>`) 

Comment: If reinstalling the plugin doesn't work, try this version [lombok-plugin-0.30-EAP.zip](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/files/4446418/lombok-plugin-0.30-EAP.zip). To install press `Ctrl + Shift + A`, Search "Install Plugin from Disk".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**2020 Edit:** Try uninstalling and reinstalling the Lombok plugin.

---

It's a temporary issue.
The github issue below says others have had luck uninstalling / reinstalling the plugin.

https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/775

If that does not work then there is a plugin you can install manually as a workaround.

**Edit**: Here are some screenshots on uninstalling/reinstalling.

Go to settings -> plugins, search for lombok under intalled. Click on the dropdown menu to show 'Uninstall'.
[image]

Click 'apply', go to the marketplace tab and click install. Then restart your IDE.

[image]

Comment: Great! uninstalling/reinstalling the plugin worked fine for me.

Comment: For 2020.2, a version downgrade to 2020.1 fixed the issue with the new 0.30 release for the 2020.1

Answer (score 4):

I just updated the intellij dependency and build it locally. For me this lombok-plugin-0.30-EAP.zip
works until the official update ist out :-) (Settings➙Plugins➙⚙️➙Install Plugin from Disk...)

Comment: how did you rebuild the plugin locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the update button there in your IDE, then just updating that Lombok plugin will work for you. As I was using the 2019.1.4 version of IntelliJ. It worked for me by just updating it. Else, uninstall it and install it again. It will install the compatible version for you.
This is the message I got after updating it
[image: This is the message I got after updating it- Image attached]

Current Lombok version which is compatible with my 2019.1 IntelliJ
[image: Current Lombok version which is compatible with my 2019.1 IntelliJ]